# Colored logs in a .log file in python

Tags: python, html, flask, logging, flask-wtforms

Printing logs code:(This prints message normally in black-white)

```
import logging

fileName="ABC.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=fileName, filemode='w',
                    level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
logging.info("Info message")
logging.error("Error message")
logging.debug("Debug message")
```

attempt at adding color to logs in log file

```
fileName="ABC.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=fileName, filemode='w',
                    level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')

colors = {'pink': '\033[95m', 'blue': '\033[94m', 'green': '\033[92m', 'yellow': '\033[93m', 'red': '\033[91m',
      'ENDC': '\033[0m', 'bold': '\033[1m', 'underline': '\033[4m'}
def str_color(color, data):
    return colors[color] + str(data) + colors['ENDC']

logging.info(str_color("green", str("Info message")))
logging.info(str_color("red", str("Error message")))
logging.info(str_color("blue", str("Debug message")))
```

Adding colors works only in terminal while in file it gives a output like:

```
[91mInfo message[0m
```

Ultimately what I want is display log file content on a html page in a Flask App

current implementation:

```
with open(fileName, "r") as f:
      content = f.read()

#content is later used in html code(like {{content}}) to print log content
```

Is there any way to achieve this, Also sorry i am a newbie in coding as well as stackoverflow.

**EDIT**
I used ansi2html library to convert the log output into a html variable like this:

```
from ansi2html import Ansi2HTMLConverter
    
    conv = Ansi2HTMLConverter()
    html = conv.convert(content)

return render_template("test.html",html=html)#Flask specific
```

```
<div>{{html | safe }}</div>
```

Issue right now i have is the default background-color it creates html is  black whereas i need white.

Comment: You'll need to use HTML markup instead of `[91m"terminal markup"[0m`

Comment: The color system you're using is ONLY when content outputs in a terminal

Comment: ANSI codes do not affect the text file and for web page you will need HTML and [probably] CSS. To make your life easier don't include them in the log.

Comment: Those escape codes for colours are not a computing universal. It is the terminal that interprets the escape codes as colours (by emulating some very old hardware). You are seeing them in your logfile because your text editor does not do that emulation. And if you want to display the colours in a web  page then you will have to generate HTML to do that. It would not be impossible to convert the escape codes to HTML `<span>` tags. But a simpler approach would be to have the web page recognize the format of the log message (INFO: etc) and supply the colour dynamically.

Comment: I have tried another method that uses ansi2html convertor but the issue i have is displaying the html file inside the existing page